# compress for all table is not reducing the size of my table

Tags: sql, oracle, compression, ddl

I have table with 10 million records which I would like to compress and thereby reduce the storage size. The table is not partitioned and has an index.

So to compress the existing table, I was issuing a command like below

```
alter table table_name compress for all operations;
```

before and after compression, the size remained as 150994944 bytes. Am I doing something wrong? I collected stats on the table as well.

I also tried `move compress` as well, that has the same effect as well

Comment: How did you check the size? The `move compress` should have done what you need.

Comment: i missed the move  keyword.. now it is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

There are two point about compression:

**1**.using package dbms_compression.get_compression_ratio you can get rate of compression on your table.

**2**.Number of columns:compression is limited to 255 columns. If you attempt to compress a table with more than 255 columns then no compression will be performed although you don't get an error message

Answer (score 0):

Setting a table to compressed does nothing with the existing data.  You have to reload the data in some way (the easiest way being 'alter table move'), and in doing so, you'll need to rebuild any indexes that end up with a status of UNUSABLE.

Note that compress 'for all operations' requires a separate license over and above that of enterprise edition.  "Basic" compression does not.